# JavaScript: How to detect a non empty input text box

Tags: javascript

I am learning JavaScript and and am working on a To Do list type of application.

Idea: "Add" button is set to disabled in the HTML and only to be enabled when there is at least one character.

My code only works when there is at least 2 characters and can't workout why it doesn't detect the first character.

The other realted question is how do I set the "add" button back to disable if the input box content has been deleted.

HTML

```
<input id="addToListInput" onkeydown="buttonStatus()" value="" type="text"><input id="addToListButton" disabled type="submit" Value="Add to list" onClick="addToList(this)">
```

JS

```
function buttonStatus() {
        var input = document.getElementById('addToListInput');
        var submit= document.getElementById('addToListButton');
        if (input.value.trim() ==""){
            submit.disabled=true;
        }else{
            submit.disabled=false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I assume the `trim` function is defined by you?

Comment: Also why dont you try jQuerys `$.trim()` http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/ and see if you get the same result

Comment: @ClydeLobo - trim is part of javascript now although isn't supported in older browsers - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Comment: @DoctorMick : Thanks for the info. I was ignorant of it. Unfortunately it will be some time before I can use it :(

Comment: Side point: @DoctorMick, is there a non-jQuery alternative to trim for supporting older broswers

Comment: @Abdi - you could use the jquery trim method (api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim) or write your own, it's fairly straight forward (http://www.sitepoint.com/trimming-strings-in-javascript/)

Comment: Thanks (as mentioned I could have easily used jquery trim but just wanted to find out how to do things natively in js first)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `keyup` instead.  By using `keydown` you are detecting when the key is down, but the textbox value has not changed at that point...

```
<input id="addToListInput" onkeyup="buttonStatus()" value="" type="text">
```

Answer (score 1):

onkeydown is fired before the input control is actually fired, if you use onkeyup it should work as you expect.